# Syntax highlighter doesn't work in blog feeds and mobile version

Tags: blogs, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I have been using [syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for my blogs which are hosted on Blogger.com, but recently I noticed that the code which has been highlighted by syntax highlighter doesn't appear on blog's feed and on mobile version. I tried to search over internet but couldn't find any useful information. I am novice to blogger/javascript and couldn't figure out why I am not able to see the formatted code.

Any kind of information will be appreciated here.

Comment: yes. i too facing this problem.

Comment: seems no one has better solution over here.

Comment: @Mdhar9e Please check the Answer below. It has answered to your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I found prettyprint syntax highlighter, which is also being used on Google website e.g developer.android.com. 
  I liked this its really easy to use and light weight.

Steps to inetgrate is shown in [prettify syntax highlighter blogs.](http://errorbuster.blogspot.com/2012/07/prettify-syntax-highlighter-for-blogger.html)